# How can i get the current state in react without redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using redux with react but i save redux for main app state, and using react hooks for non-shared state between components.

For Example, i have a navbar menu items, every item color should turn blue once get clicked, so my mind goes to **useState** to change the item that get clicked and add a class **.active** to it.

The problem i face is that i do not get the latest state, but i get the previous state and i understand that setting state in react is asynchronous and batched.

**Demo Code:**

Component

```
 const [targets, getTarget] = useState([]);
 const addTarget = (e) => {
   getTarget([e.target]);
 }

 const handleOnItemClick = (e, category) => {
    addTarget(e);
    console.log(targets) // return [] on first click
 } 

myFunctionToAddAcTiveClass () {
  //i need to use state here but i could not
 // because it does not return the latest state
}

return(
 <ul className="categories-list-items d-flex justify-content-between mb-4">
      {items.map((item, index) => {
         return (
            <li
               key={index}
               onClick={(e) => handleOnItemClick(e, category)}
            >
             {item}
           </li>
         );
     })}
 </ul>
)
```

Is there a way to get the right item on every click to add the **.active** class??

Comment: The non-hook way is to pass a callback to `setState`, the hook way is to use `useEffect`. However I'm not sure that's even necessary here; which item is the active one is part of the state, and your JSX should assign the class based on state. Can you add the `myFunctionToAddAcTiveClass()` version that you tried?

Comment: i am using some complex way to achieve that , but the bottle neck point is that  i could not get the current state, thank you, i think yes you are right useEffect would be the right solution here

Comment: Note that you're using very misleading names for your functions. It's supposed to be `const [targets, setTargets] = useState([])`. Since your edit you seem to only have a single target though,  in which case `addTarget` is misleading and an array is not needed. Here's a live example showing how to deal with a bunch of items where one is active: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-cloud-vv3ob

Comment: @ChrisG thanks chris, that was for demo , but please add your answer so i can accept, your solution is so helpful!!